# Merge two queries together

Tags: php, mysql

Oke my website works with Facebook Api, it will import all the friends (userId, name) of the user that will be logged in so my table structure is as following:

```
users: id, name
usersFriends: id, friendUserId, name
```

So when the users join the website, they will get all the friends imported, example data:

```
user: 237374734 (facebook user id), John brouwers (name of the user)
```

then it will import all the friends of John. for example:

```
userFriends: 237374734 (John user id), 2737373, Michael jackson
```

Now what I need is a query that will SEARCH (by name) through the friends, which is
no problem with just a join, but what I need is in the query I need to CHECK whether the user is on my website so lets take an example:

We logged in with the user John, and we are searching for michael so that would be

```
SELECT name FROM userFriends WHERE name LIKE %michael%
```

But what I need is NOT only return the name of the user, I also need a CHECK whether the user exists in the users table.

Sorry for the long story, hope that my question is clear. Thanks already!

Comment: Please put your table structure if you want quick solution.

Comment: You name the friendships? OK…

Comment: Its from Facebook, it imports all the users and the names, else you got to make a query to facebook each time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** So you need a query that search friends by Name and check whether the friend exists in the users table or not, As follows:

```
create table Users(
   Id int not null,
   primary key (Id),
   Name varchar(50) not null
)TYPE=MyISAM;
create table UserFriends(
   Id int not null,
   foreign key (Id) references Users(Id),
   FriendUserId int not null,
   Name varchar(50) not null
)Type=MyISAM;
insert into Users(Id,Name) values(237374734,'John brouwers');
insert into UserFriends(Id,FriendUserId,Name)
values(237374734, 2737373, 'Michael jackson');
```

Here is the query that will search for the suer that his name `like "%Michael%"` and check if he is a registered user or not:

```
select s.Id, s.Name, 
       case when exists 
       ( 
           select Name from users where Name like "%Michael%" 
       ) Then 'Registered User'
       else
       (
           'Not Registered'
       )
       end
       as 'Is Registered in My Website'
from 
(
      select uf.FriendUserId Id, uf.Name
      from UserFriends uf
      left join users u on u.Id = uf.friendUserId
      where uf.name like "%Michael%"
) s
```

This will gives you:

```
Id              Name        Is Registered in My Website
2737373   Michael jackson        Not Registered
```

Hope this will be helpful and if there is any problems don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: This is where I'm heading at. But the query output should just be like this: array('id', 'name', 'onWebsite') so the 'onWebsite' should be checked in the query, how do I do this?

Comment: No guys, read my question again. Once again, I said, I want a query that gets all the friends of the user but at the same time make a check whether the friend exists in the users table (this is not required) and this check should be called for example 'onWebsite' do you understand?

Comment: @user1066101 Sorry about all of that,so how do you want this checked to be called `onWebsite` do you select a new column to be called that and have the check values tru or false???

Comment: @user1066101, yes a little bit but if you Post the structure of the two tables and a sample data and the exected data that you want this will be easer. i will update my answer but for the final part need to done in a separated query. and sorry again for that but u just try to help.

Comment: It's not problem its very nice that you are trying to help, lemme rephrase my question sec.

Comment: @user1066101, Is this query resolved the first part that you ask for??

Comment: nope, and you say the second query, my question was merge 2 queries together, that was my whole point, if it is possible to merge those two queries (to search for the user, and if the user exists in the user table to give an true or false)

Comment: @user1066101 i can't test all these things right now, so let me today and i will give you the final answer 'ISA'.

Comment: @user1066101 Hope this will be the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select users.id
from users join usersFriends on users.id = usersFriends.friendUserId
where usersFriends.userId = ?
```

Comment: Read the question again, I don't need a join, I want to check whether the friend is in the users table

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.userId 
from users u, usersFriends uf
where u.userId=uf.friendUserId and
u.userId=?
```

Take sometime to study [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29). It is very useful.

Comment: I don't need a join query, I need a query that will get all the friends of the user and also check whether that friend record exists in the users table

Comment: I updated my example to show you that it does work, you only need to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JOIN for that. Consider the following sample query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM users u, usersFriends uf
WHERE uf.friendUserId = u.id
AND uf.userId = ?
```

A query like this should work, please mind that as we don't know the exact field names you have, you'd need to make some adjustments.

**UPDATE**

```
To show you that it DOES work:

create table users (id int, name varchar(100));
create table usersFriends (friendUserId int, userId int);
insert into users values (1, 'name 1'), (2, 'name 2'), (3, 'name 3');
insert into usersFriends values (1, 7), (5, 7);


mysql> SELECT u.id, u.name FROM users u, usersFriends uf
    -> WHERE uf.friendUserId = u.id
    -> AND uf.userId =7;
+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | name 1 |
+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but, the query is not correct, I need a query that will also CHECK whether the user exists, it is possible that a friend user is not in the database do you understand?

Comment: The query WILL do that, that's how a LEFT JOINT (which is implicit in the query, if you are using MySQL) will do. It will only return the records that exist in both usersFriend and users tables.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would have a foreign constraint between your `usersFriends` table and the `users` table. This ensures that there will always be a corresponding `users` record. To set up a foreign key you will need to ensure that your tables are both InnoDB and to add the constraint, you could then use:

```
ALTER TABLE usersFriends ADD FOREIGN KEY (friendUserId) REFERENCES users (id);
```

Otherwise, you can use a join

```
SELECT *
FROM usersFriends f
    JOIN users u on f.friendUserId = u.ID
WHERE f.userId = ?
```

Comment: I know I can use a join to get the user information but this is not what I want, sorry the question might be a little bit vague but what I need is to chck whether the friend does exist in the users table